# SQL Query to select false if any one value in column is false

Tags: sql

I have two tables in SQL.
The first one is master and second one contains details.
I want to get all records from table1 and True/ False from Table2.
The condition is
If all the values are true -> return true
If all the values are false -> return false
If any one/more value(s) is false -> return false

The details are as follows

```
Table 1 
ID, Name
1, A
2, B
3, C

Table 2
ID, Date, Visited 
1,20230101,True
1,20230102,True
1,20230103,True
2,20230101,False
2,20230102,False
2,20230103,False
3,20230101,True
3,20230102,False
3,20230103,True
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
1,A,True 
2, B, False
3, C, False
```

Is it possible without a procedure?
So far, I have tried to check on Id and count(Visited) by grouping on id, visited and if the count is same as count(*), return the value.
But failing to do it in single query.

Comment: GROUP BY. use MIN to get False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you only have those two values `True` or `False`, this simple query will do:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.name, MIN(t2.visited) AS visited
FROM
  table1 t1 
  INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY 
  t1.id, t1.name;
```

The idea is the function `MIN` takes `False` if occuring at least once (because F comes before T), otherwise it takes `True` because no further values are possible.
If you're not sure if further values are possible, you could extend the query and add a `CASE` to explicitly check if there is at least one row with `False` :

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.name,
  CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(CASE t2.visited WHEN 'False' THEN 1 END) = 0 
      THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS visited
FROM
  table1 t1 
  INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY 
  t1.id, t1.name;
```

The first query is likely sufficient in your use case. Only use the second one if further values appear and you are no longer sure if the `False` value would still be the minimum one. Or if `True` will be renamed to `Alright` or similar things happen.

Here a [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/uesfblv9) based on your sample data that shows a possible case there is a difference between the two queries.
Note the fiddle doesn't contain a date column because it doesn't matter for the queries.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I only have true and false, so even the first query should work. Have tested it on some sample data and gives me required output.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, based on your sample data, this is best suited for *exists*; by joining both tables you are reading all rows from Table2 when you don't need to.

```
select Id, Name,
 case when exists (
     select 0 from t2 
     where t2.Id = t1.Id and t2.Visited = 'False'
    ) then 'False' else 'True'
  end Visited
from t1;
```

Comment: This approach is also good as we can add more columns in select. But it fails when there is no matching records in t2, as it returns True in that case.

Comment: Yes in that scenario, which is not in your question, you need an outer join.

Comment: Thanks Stu, let me check by adding outer join

Answer (score 0):

This below `SQL` should work. As I don't have exact table at my end, I couldn't test. But concept should work.

```
with cte_getMax as 
(
    select a.id, a.name, max(len(b.visited)) max_len
        from table_1 a
        join table_2 b
        on (a.id = b.id)
        group by a.id, a.name
)
select id, name, 
       case when max_len = 5 then 'False' else 'True' end flag
    from cte_getMax;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more simple query:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, COALESCE(t2.Visited, 'True') AS Visited
    FROM Table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
            ON t2.id=t1.id and t2.Visited = 'False'
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.Visited
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

Main idea:

- `Table1` is main as query result simply add one more field to `Table1` structure.
- `LEFT JOIN` to be sure that all `Table1` records will be in result and `GROUP BY` to be sure that result will have 1 record for each ID.
- `t2.Visited = 'False'` condition filters only records that have `False` as `Visited`
- if no any `False` for `ID` then result will have `NULL` as `Visited` so change null value to desired `True`

---

*UPDATE:*

Fixed statement thanks to @JonasMetzler comment.

Comment: Basically ok, but you need to add t1.name to the GROUP BY clause (or put it in an aggregate function, but I don't think you want to do that).

Comment: Thanks. I will check this approach as well.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I think `t1.name` not needed in this particular case because all records with `t1.ID` has the same `t1.Name`.

Comment: @Serg See https://dbfiddle.uk/Ulc5a50J

Comment: @JonasMetzler You are right, thank you very much for your comments. Updated statement to fix it.